# Using the Parse iOS sdk how do I retrieve the session class for the current user

Tags: ios, parse-platform, sdk

I'm using the Parse iOS sdk and I'm interested in adding some additional fields to the session class. How do I go about retrieving a session. I've tried just doing a query based on the current user, but it never seems to work.

```
        PFQuery *sessionQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Session"];
        //[sessionQuery whereKey:@"user" equalTo:currentuser];

        [sessionQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *session, NSError *error) {
            // comments now contains the comments for myPost
            if (!session) {
                NSLog(@"Could not find a session metching your parameters");
                NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Found the session bound to this user%@", session);
            }
        }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to query for it and can access it directly in iOS using the following

```
PFUser.currentUser()?.sessionToken
```

Some important things to note about session tokens [from the documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#sessions)

> PFSession objects can only be accessed by the user specified in the
>   user field. All PFSession objects have an ACL that is read and write
>   by that user only. You cannot change this ACL. This means querying for
>   sessions will only return objects that match the current logged-in
>   user.

In other words, querying for sessions will only be useful if you plan on allowing users to view all of their sessions and revoke them individually, [as mentioned in this blog post](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/announcing-new-enhanced-sessions/).

> - Find, Delete — Useful for building a UI screen that allows users to see their active session on all devices, and log out of sessions on
>     other devices. If your app does not have this feature, you should
>     disable these permissions.
> - Get, Update, Add Field — Unless you need these operations, you should disable these permissions.

I'm curious what information you would like to store inside the session object that makes more sense there than it would inside of the installation or user objects. Hope this helps!

Comment: well I'm also authenticating using another API ( but you must be logged into Parse first ). My thought was to store the authToken and refreshToken in the same table, since parse would take care of destroying it when the session has expired .... but now I'm not so sure this is the right method

Comment: It's hard to say what the best approach may be without knowing more about the external API you're authenticating with but it could make sense to store the data in the `session` objects. From the docs: *PFSession is a subclass of PFObject, so you can query, update, and delete sessions in the same way that you manipulate normal objects on Parse.*

Comment: That being said, there are certainly a bunch of limitations you will have to carefully navigate around such as: *Unlike other Parse objects, the PFSession class does not have Cloud Code triggers. So you cannot register a beforeSave or afterSave handler for the Session class.*